# Does $f:[0,\infty )\times \Omega \to \mathbb R$ being progressively measurable and being measurable and adapted are equivalent?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\{\mathcal F_t\},\mathbb P)$ a probability space. In the book of Oksendal (SDE), they define the Itô integral on $\mathcal V(0,T)$ being the set of stochastic process $f:[0,\infty )\times \Omega \to \mathbb R$ being :

(1) $\mathcal B\otimes \mathcal F-$measurable (where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma-$algebra of $[0,\infty )$).

(2) $\mathcal F_t-$adapted

(3) $\mathbb E\int_0^T f^2(s,\cdot )ds<\infty $.

In the book of Baldi (stochastic calculus), he define the Itô integral on $\mathcal M^2(0,T)$ being the set of stochastic process $f:[0,\infty )\times \Omega \to \mathbb R$ being

(a) Progressively measurable

(b) $\mathbb E\int_0^T f(s,\cdot )^2ds<\infty $.

---

**Question :** Does (1) and (2) is equivalent to (a) ? I have the impression that (a) is stronger than (1) and (2), but I may be wrong. Indeed, even if $f$ is $\mathcal B\otimes \mathcal F$ measurable and $f(t,\cdot )$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable, I'm not so sure why $f|_{[0,t]\times \Omega }$ would be $\mathcal B([0,t])\otimes \mathcal F_t$ measurable. Any idea ?

I denote $\mathcal B(A)$ the borel $\sigma -$algebra of the set $A$.

Comment: (a) is stronger. Baldi is making a stronger assumption.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you. So, if $f$ satisfies (1) and (2), how can I be sure that $I_t=\int_0^t f(s,\cdot )ds$ is $\mathcal F_t$ adapted ? If $f$ is progressively measurable, then obviously it is, but if it's not, how can I be sure that  $(I_t,\mathcal F_t)$ is a stochastic process ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Maybe because $$\int_0^t f(s,\cdot )ds=\int_0^\infty  1_{[0,t]}f(s,\cdot )ds.$$ Now, maybe that $s\mapsto 1_{[0,t]}(s)f(s,\cdot )$ is $\mathcal B\otimes \mathcal F_t$ measurable ? And thus, the result yields with Fubini theorem. But how from $\mathcal B\otimes \mathcal F$ beaing measurable, I can prove that $\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]}f(s,\cdot )$ is $\mathcal B\otimes \mathcal F_t$ measurable ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Is my previous interpretation correct for $\int_0^t f(s,\cdot )ds$ being $\mathcal F_t$ adapted ?